# How to disable indentation of enum methods?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, code-formatting

Given:

```
public enum Test
{
    ONE
    {
        public String toString()
        {
            return "foo";
        }
    },
    TWO
    {
        public String toString()
        {
            return "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 is indenting the braces containing the methods as follows:

```
public enum Test
{
    ONE
        {
            public String toString()
            {
                return "foo";
            }
        },
    TWO
        {
            public String toString()
            {
                return "bar";
            }
        }
}
```

I could not find any code-formatting setting to change this behavior. **Is there a way to keep the braces on the same indentation level as the enum constants?**

(I do not wish to change the continuation indentation for non-enum code)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatted output shown in your question implies that you have the following configuration under `Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces`

[image]

The choice of `Next Line` for "class", "method" and "Other" results in the opening curly brackets being put on the next line for the class `Test`, the `toString()` methods and the enum names.

If I understand your question correctly then the issue is with the indent for the opening curly bracket of each enum. You can control this in `Editor > Code Style > Java > Tabs and Indents` by setting `Continuation Indent` to `0`. For example:

[image]

Note: this setting is not specific to enums; it will change the continuation indent for other types too. There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106353) in YourTrack requesting support for continuation indents specific to enums but no there is progress on that issue thus far. Until the changes requested in that issue are implemented the closest you'll get on IntelliJ is changing continuation indents for all types, as per this answer.

Comment: That is an issue for me. I don't want to use a continuation indent of 0 for the rest of my code. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: In that case there is no support in IntelliJ for continuation indent settings specific to enums, see the comment below your question from @CrazyCoder

Comment: Okay. Please add this clarification (and link) to your answer and I will mark it as accepted.